# I want to redirect to next page using ajax but it could work

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to redirect to next page using jQuery ajax but it could work .i am new to jQuery and ajax and didn't know about much of its syntax kindly help

I already search to many things related to this but it could not help me

```
<link href="~/Content/Sidecontroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="nav-content">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active">
            <a class="move" href="/Home/Index">
                <span class="icon-home"></span>
                <span class="text">home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="move" href="/Service/Userdata">
                <span class="icon-user"></span>
                <span class="text">User</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="move" href="/Service/Stockdata">
                <span class="icon-headphones"></span>
                <span class="text">Stock</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="move" href="#">
                <span class="icon-picture"></span>
                <span class="text">Pos</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/Script.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.move').bind('click', function(e) {           
        var url = $(this).find("a[href]").attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : url,
            success : function(response) {
                window.location.href =url;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your AJAX request seems entirely pointless as you send no data and you're not dealing with anything in the response, you just request the URL through AJAX, then redirect to it regardless. Is there a specific reason you feel the need to use AJAX at all here?

Comment: No specific reason just try to learn jQuery ajax. i just started it one day ago and didn't know much about its syntax.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer for you below. The AJAX itself is fine, the problem is with the way you retrieve the `href` attribute

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you very very much for help.

Comment: I already did, scroll down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your logic is because the `.move` element is the `a` which holds the `href` attribute, yet you call `find()` on that, which returns nothing.

To fix your problem simply remove the `find()` call. Also note that `bind()` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Replace it with `on()` instead. I'd also suggest you check the version of jQuery you're using. The latest is 3.4.1.

```js
$('.move').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
      window.location.assign(url);
    }
  });
});
```

There's a couple of other things to note here. Firstly, the AJAX request in this example is almost entirely redundant as you send no data to it, and do nothing with the response before making the redirect. You state in the comments that this is just a learning exercise, so the above is just something to be aware of.

Secondly, I updated the redirect to use the `assign()` method instead of setting the `href` property. This is a personal preference as either will work, but IMO redirecting is an action and should be achieved through a method call.